# Login doesn't work + Symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication

**UPDATE:**

I've updated my Users Entity so that it implements the AdvancedUserInterface and the necessary functions.

```
<?php

namespace VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_users_roles1_idx", columns={"role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_username", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_firstname", type="string", length=45, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userFirstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_surname", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSurname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_type", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userType;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_password", type="string", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_salt", type="string", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userSalt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_token", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userToken;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_created", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $userCreated;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_modified", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userModified = null;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_deleted", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userDeleted = null;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_lastlogin", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLastlogin = null;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_confirmed", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userConfirmed = null;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_locked", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $userLocked = null;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $userId;

    /**
     * @var \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     * })
     */
    private $role;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_teams",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="team_id", referencedColumnName="team_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $team;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_follows_competitions",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="competition_id", referencedColumnName="competition_id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $competition;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->team = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->competition = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
        $this->userSalt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
    }


    /**
     * Set userUsername
     *
     * @param string $userUsername
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserUsername($userUsername)
    {
        $this->userUsername = $userUsername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userUsername
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserUsername()
    {
        return $this->userUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Set userFirstname
     *
     * @param string $userFirstname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserFirstname($userFirstname)
    {
        $this->userFirstname = $userFirstname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userFirstname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserFirstname()
    {
        return $this->userFirstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSurname
     *
     * @param string $userSurname
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSurname($userSurname)
    {
        $this->userSurname = $userSurname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSurname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserSurname()
    {
        return $this->userSurname;
    }

    /**
     * Set userEmail
     *
     * @param string $userEmail
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserEmail($userEmail)
    {
        $this->userEmail = $userEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userEmail
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserEmail()
    {
        return $this->userEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param string $userType
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set userPassword
     *
     * @param string $userPassword
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserPassword($userPassword)
    {
        $this->userPassword = $userPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userPassword
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserPassword()
    {
        return $this->userPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set userSalt
     *
     * @param string $userSalt
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserSalt($userSalt)
    {
        $this->userSalt = $userSalt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userSalt
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserSalt()
    {
        return $this->userSalt;
    }

    /**
     * Set userToken
     *
     * @param string $userToken
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserToken($userToken)
    {
        $this->userToken = $userToken;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userToken
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserToken()
    {
        return $this->userToken;
    }

    /**
     * Set userCreated
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userCreated
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserCreated($userCreated)
    {
        $this->userCreated = $userCreated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userCreated
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserCreated()
    {
        return $this->userCreated;
    }

    /**
     * Set userModified
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userModified
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserModified($userModified)
    {
        $this->userModified = $userModified;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userModified
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserModified()
    {
        return $this->userModified;
    }

    /**
     * Set userDeleted
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userDeleted
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserDeleted($userDeleted)
    {
        $this->userDeleted = $userDeleted;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userDeleted
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserDeleted()
    {
        return $this->userDeleted;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLastlogin
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLastlogin
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLastlogin($userLastlogin)
    {
        $this->userLastlogin = $userLastlogin;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLastlogin
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLastlogin()
    {
        return $this->userLastlogin;
    }

    /**
     * Set userConfirmed
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userConfirmed
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserConfirmed($userConfirmed)
    {
        $this->userConfirmed = $userConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userConfirmed
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserConfirmed()
    {
        return $this->userConfirmed;
    }

    /**
     * Set userLocked
     *
     * @param \DateTime $userLocked
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setUserLocked($userLocked)
    {
        $this->userLocked = $userLocked;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userLocked
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUserLocked()
    {
        return $this->userLocked;
    }

    /**
     * Get userId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getUserId()
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * Set role
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setRole(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles $role = null)
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get role
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Roles
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * Add team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team[] = $team;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove team
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team
     */
    public function removeTeam(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Teams $team)
    {
        $this->team->removeElement($team);
    }

    /**
     * Get team
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getTeam()
    {
        return $this->team;
    }

    /**
     * Add competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition[] = $competition;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove competition
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition
     */
    public function removeCompetition(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Competitions $competition)
    {
        $this->competition->removeElement($competition);
    }

    /**
     * Get competition
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCompetition()
    {
        return $this->competition;
    }

    private $player;

    /**
     * Get player
     *
     * @return \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players
     */

    public function getPlayer() {
        return $this->player;
    }
    /**
     * Set player
     *
     * @param \VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setPlayer(\VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Players $player = null){
        $this->player = $player;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->userUsername;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->userSalt;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->userPassword;
    }


    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of UserInterface method
     *
     * @return array Roles
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return ['ROLE_USER'];
    }


    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Implementation of AdvancedUserInterface method
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        // CHECK IF $this->confirmed is not null
        return true;
    }
}
```

But I still can't get logged in. Am I still missing something? 
My login view:

```
    {% extends "::securitybase.html.twig" %}

{% block title %}Login | {{ parent() }}{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {% set class_error = ' has-error alert alert-warning' %}
    <h1 class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">Please sign on</h1>
    {% if loginError %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">{{ loginError.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_errors(loginForm) }}
    {{ form_start(loginForm, {"attr": {"class": "form-horizontal"} }) }}
    <div class="form-group{{ loginForm.userUsername.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
        {{ form_label(loginForm.userUsername, label|default(),
        { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                {{ form_widget(loginForm.userUsername,
                {"attr": {"class": "form-control" } }) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not loginForm.userUsername.vars.valid %}
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                {{ form_errors(loginForm.userUsername) }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group{{ loginForm.userPassword.vars.valid ? '' : class_error }}">
        {{ form_label(loginForm.userPassword, label|default(),
        { "label_attr": { "class": "col-sm-3 control-label"}}) }}
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                {{ form_widget(loginForm.userPassword,
                {"attr": {"class": "form-control" } }) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        {% if not loginForm.userPassword.vars.valid %}
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> <strong>Please fix:</strong></h5>
                {{ form_errors(userPassword.userUsername) }}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember" checked>
                <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            {{ form_widget(loginForm.btn_login,
            {"attr": {"class": "btn btn-primary"} }) }}
            <a href="{{ path('volley_scout_registerpage') }}" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(loginForm) }}
{% endblock %}
```

My loginAction:

```
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    // New user
    $user = new Users();

    $form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), $user);

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return $this->render('VolleyScoutBundle:User:login.html.twig', array(
        'loginForm'  => $form->createView(),
        'loginError' => $error,
    ));
}
```

My security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        VolleyScout\VolleyScoutBundle\Entity\Users:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 15

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER]

    providers:
        members:
            entity:
                class: VolleyScoutBundle:Users
                property: userUsername

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
        secured_area:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: volley_scout_loginpage
                check_path: volley_scout_logincheck
                username_parameter: login[username]
                password_parameter: login[password]
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: volley_scout_homepage
            logout:
                path:   volley_scout_logout
                target: volley_scout_loginpage
            remember_me:
                 key:      "%secret%"
                 lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                 path:     /
                 domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
                 remember_me_parameter: remember

    access_control:
         - { path: /_wdt/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: /_profiler/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: /login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: /register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
         - { path: /admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
         - { path: /.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**UPDATE 2:**
When I check my dev.log file I get the following error:

```
[2014-01-17 18:20:46] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate". [] []
```

Every time I try to login ..

Comment: I suggest you to look at the [Entity Provider documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html), the `UserInterface` will help you to implement the `User` class. Note that `Entity` are often called by a singular noun. You have many users but each one is an instance of `User`, in my opinion it's easier to think at each entity by a singular noun.

Comment: Your basic problem is that your user object does not implement the user interface which means that the built in login checker will not kick in.  The security system is one of Symfony's more challenging bundles.  I would suggest creating a new symfony project and then follow the steps in the security chapter and get yourself a working system.  Once you have a clear idea of how all the pieces fit together you can then go ahead and make your own custom user.

Comment: Can you add the login view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just what @Cerad mentioned, you are not implementing the `UserInterface` or the `AdvancedUserInterface`.  Take a look at the docs [How To load users from the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html) and it will give you some examples of how you can do this.  By implementing the `AdvancedUserInterface`, you can also use other cool features like managing `roles` in the database, locking out users that are not 'active', or other cool features.  Take a look at the article and I'm sure it will give you the answer.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

class Users implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    //.....
}
```

Just make sure that you add the required `getters` to your user class.

For the `UserInterface`, you need these functions:

```
getRoles()
getPassword()
getSalt()
getUsername()
eraseCredentials()
```

For the `AdvancedUserInterface`, you need all the above and also

```
isAccountNonExpired()
isAccountNonLocked()
isCredentialsNonExpired()
isEnabled()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still not getting logged in. I've updated my begin post. There's probably still a little mistake, could you take a look at it?

Comment: I also have a feeling that your username and password field names may be an issue.  do you think you could try changing `login[username]` to just `username` and same for password?

Comment: I've checked my dev.log and I always get an error when I try to login. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: that is not an error, it is a debug message.  Is there a reason you are using a form class for your login form? The whole purpose of a form class is so that you can re-use the form.  Do you really need to re-use the login form?  I would just follow the example in the docs and build a static form in html.

Answer (score 1):

PLease try to use https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle - it'll help you to save a couple of hours, or more. This is reliable bundle for registrating, loging and managing users. Also provides you to change security, send emails or change password.

It helps me in many of our projects.

Answer (score 0):

Does the csrf protection token display well in your login view ?

You can try to add

```
{{ form_rest(loginForm) }}
```

somewhere inside your form if it's not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still not getting logged in. I've updated my begin post. There's probably still a little mistake, could you take a look at it?